# Java String to Char Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, char

```
String c="12345";
for(char k:c.toCharArray())
System.out.print(k+4);
```

This program outputs:
5354555657

I don't really understand why this is out putting those numbers. The only pattern I see is that it prints a "5" then takes the "1" from the string and adds 2 to make "3". Then prints a "5" then takes the "2" from the string and adds 2 to make "4" then prints a "5" and so on.

Comment: https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: It prints 53|54|55|56|57. Just adds 4 to the ascii values of the respective characters. (for eg: "1" has ASCII of 49 => Add 4 => 53)

Comment: Each `char` can be treated as numeric value, representing its index in Unicode Table. Also in Java `char + int = int` which means that when we end up with `'1'+4` it is evaluated as `49` ([index of character `'1'`](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=1)) incremented by `4` which is `53`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters in the array, when promoted to `int` for the addition of `4`, take on their underlying Unicode value, of which the [ASCII values](https://www.asciitable.com/) are a subset.  The digits 0-9 are represented by codes 48-57 respectively.  Characters `'1'` through `'5'` are 49-53, then you add 4 and get 53-57.

After adding, cast the sum back to `char` so `print` can interpret it as a `char`.

```
System.out.print( (char) (k+4));
```

Output:

```
56789
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're adding an int to a character (it's casting your character to an int and then adding it to 4, then printing it out).

You need to do:

```
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(k) + 4);
```

Comment: Awesome response! This is for a UIL question my kids are having on the written portion of Computer Science.

Comment: The ASCII for k is 107 though, so I don't think I am following you.

Comment: @TroyWalker `k` is *valuable* holding as *value* characters like `'1'`, `'2'`, you need to look at their indexes.

Comment: @TroyWalker - it's the ascii values for the numerical character, not k.  For instance, 1 in ascii is 47, 2 is 48, etc (it's casting the char to an int).  Adding those to the value of k gives you your output above.